# How to extract a pattern from a file and append to another on linux

Tags: linux, terminal, command-line

I've a txt file that contains a web page source code , i want to extract all links that contains "https://ANYTHING.amazonaws.com" in it to a new file.

The new file will contain:

```
https://test-ok.amazonaws.com
https://hhhhh.hhhh.amazonaws.com
https://anything.dd.dd.amazonaws.com
```

the links doesn't have to be in a specific tag or something, they can be anywhere in any tag!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` to search for a regex pattern with `-o` flag to print only the matching fragments and then redirect output to a new file.

In your case probably this one should work:

```bash
grep -o 'https://.*\.amazonaws\.com' sourcecode.html > newfile
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet) you can find regular expression syntax cheatsheet.